# Difference between outputs of standard and legacy SQL in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, legacy-sql

I have a query written in legacy SQL mode which I want to rewrite into StandardSQL. It has a few inner joins, and standardSQL has a few places where I have to unnest data using UNNEST functions (arrays of product IDs inside a row of transactionID).

However, after rewriting and comparing outputs I noticed that the one in standardSQL has slightly fewer rows (194310 vs 193907).

Is there any general reason why this happens, and how to avoid it?

Comment: Slightly different?! It's 174,920 off. Or is that a typo? I'd suspect you made an mistake in your port to standard somewhere along the line.

Comment: @GrahamPolley a typo, forgot one digit in second number

Comment: You might want LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN. Please share the queries themselves or examples.